# Method to determine redirect after login

Tags: c#, beginner, http

I have a method that returns a URL to send a user should they pass a login.  My problem is two of these links are hard coded one of which is attempting to pass a variable to the model of that controller.  My question is two fold:

A. Is this safe
B. Is there a better way to do this without hard-coding things like this?

```
public class LoginViewModel
{
  public string UserId {get; set;}
  public string GetAppAccess()
  {
    using (var db = new WebContext())
    {
      var query = (from a in db.Permissions
                   join b in db.UserPermissions on a.PermissionId equals b.PermissionId
                   join c in db.Applications on a.Name equals c.AppName
                   where a.PermissionType == PermissionType.AppAccess & b.UserId == UserId
                   select c).ToList();
      switch (query.Count)
      {
        case 0:
          return "http://SERVERNAME/Tickets/Create?subject=Request%20For%20Application%20Access";
          // TODO: code ticket logic to except this argument
        case 1:
          return query[0].AppUrl;
        default:
          return "http://SERVERNAME/Dashboard/" + UserId;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is stopping anyone from "saving" the target URL for later/continued/unauthorized use?

Comment: That would be handled by the controller they land on and user authentication.

Comment: Are the return urls on different domains?  Is this using MVC .NET?  If so have you considered using RedirectToAction?

Comment: @dreza I have considered RedirectToAction, however I was trying to keep this logic out of the controller, maybe I could throw a using statement in there and utilize the RedirectToAction in the model...

Comment: @aaronmallen how and when is the viewmodel used by the rest of the application?  i.e. could you post your controller and or action code.

Comment: @dreza it is used in the index of the HomeController.

Comment: @aaronmallen I assume it's used in the view as well? i.e. You use GetAppAccess() in your view somewhere??

Comment: No not in the view, the entire point is to determine where to redirect the user after login.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct in feeling uneasy about the hardcoded URLs: I would put them in a config file.

By hardcoding them you will be forced to rebuild the project should you change to a different server while using a configuration file you can change it whenever you want and it will get picked up automatically.

Comment: What about creating a variable that pulls the servername based on the URL?